# El método 'transaction' es null cordovaSQlite

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, cordova

Hola estoy usando el siguiente código para conectarme a una base de datos en `sqlite` y funciona bien pero luego de un tiempo aparece este error cuando intento ejecutar un select:

> Cannot call method 'transaction' of null

```
 angular.element(document).ready(function () {
       if(window.cordova){
    db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: 'app.db',location='default' });
       }else{
    db = window.openDatabase("app.db", "1.0", "app.db", 2000000);

        }  
    });
```

Estoy utilizando cordova + angularjs 1.5 y hago pruebas en un celular con la versión de android 6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

logre encontrar una respuesta a mi problema

primero utilice  lo siguiente para verificar errores, y el error se encontraba al usar lo siguiente

> db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: 'app.db',location='default' });

por alguna razon no puedo abrir la base de datos con el plugin de sqlite.

```
app.factory('cordovaSQLite', function ($cordovaSQLite, $q) {
    var self = this;
    // Handle query's and potential errors
    self.execute = function (dbx, query, parameters) {
        parameters = parameters || [];
        var q = $q.defer();

        angular.element(document).ready(function () {
            $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, parameters)
                    .then(function (result) {
                        q.resolve(result);
                    }, function (error) {
                        console.warn('I found an error');
                        console.warn(error);
                        q.reject(error);
                    });
        });
        return q.promise;
    };


    return self;
});
```

así que opte por dejarlo de la siguiente forma y no se  presentó mas el problema

```
 angular.element(document).ready(function () {

     db = window.openDatabase("app.db", "1.0", "app.db", 2000000);

 });
```